# Struggling with Validating the following Body Response in Postman

Tags: json, validation, postman

I have been trying to validate the following data from a body.

I have schema that validates the properties like Account ID and Associate number and that is fine, but what I want to drill down on the validation.

This below is the console and body response

From `})` I get the below:

(1) [{,,,}] (not sure if those are commas or periods)

(0): [{,,,}]
AccountID: xxxx,
AssociateNumber: xxxx,
AssociateType: "Account",
AccountType: "PRIVATE AVIA",
DisplayName: "Jet Masters Air",

**Body Response**

```
[
    {
        "AccountID": xxxx,
        "AssociateNumber": xxxx,
        "AssociateType": "Account",
        "AccountType": "PRIVATE AVIA",
        "DisplayName": "Jet Masters Air",
    }
]   


//Im trying the following:

pm.test("Verify the Role name ", function () { 
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.expect(jsonData.property.items.DisplayName).to.eql("Jet Masters Air")
})
```

Resolution:

pm.test("Verify the Role name ", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); pm.expect(jsonData[0].DisplayName).to.eql("Jet Masters Air") })

Comment: Try `jsonData[0].property.`

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. Appreciate it!!

Comment: It would be `jsonData[0].DisplayName ` based on that response. Not sure where you're getting `items.property`

Comment: This was correct I had the [0] in the wrong placement in the code and this was not being recognized. Once I moved it to the correct place with your assistance. The validation that I was looking to execute on the response is now working. Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: You should add your working solution as the answer and close this out.

Comment: Resolved:                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                   
pm.test("Verify the Role name ", function () { 
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].DisplayName).to.eql("Jet Masters Air")
})